# C recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int func(int n0, int n);

int main ()
{
    int n0, n, nFinal=0;
    printf ("Enter constant (n0): ");
    scanf ("%d", &n0);
    printf ("Enter the number of iteractions (n): ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    nFinal = func(n0, n);
    printf ("nFinal after %d iteractions is %d: \n", n, nFinal);
    return 0;
}

int func(int n0, int n){
    int i,nFinal=0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        nFinal = (nFinal*nFinal) + n0;
    }

    return nFinal;
}
```

The nFinal is calculated within a for loop. I would like to achieve the same result but doing a recursive function.

From what I see, I cannot change the function call because I always need the start number and the number of iterations. Therefore, after the first iteration, the program would have to call again `nFinal = func (n0, n);` but as I need at each iteration of the calculated value of nFinal, I will have to change this.

Is it possible to make a recursive function but maintaining the function as `nFinal = func (n0, n);`?

Can someone point me some way?

Comment: In the body of your function `func` you have used `nFinal` before it has been initialised. Is this correct?

Comment: @Chris Sorry. nFinal is initialized to zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your function

```
int func(int n0, int n){
    int i,nFinal=0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        nFinal = (nFinal*nFinal) + n0;
    }

    return nFinal;
}
```

If n is (less than) 0, your result is 0. Then the new value of nFinal is the old value of nFinal^2 + n0, so you get:

```
int func(int n0, int n){
    if (n <= 0) return 0;

    int f = func(n0, n-1);
    return f*f + n0;
}
```

Comment: Oops, thought I got an error and deleted, but it seems to be alright.

Comment: Thanks.It's working but I have 1 doubt.I understand that `f = func(n0, n-1)` will be recursive until n<=0. At this point f will have the value 0. The problem is that I'm not understanding the `return f*f + n0`.At this point it will not be `0*0+n0`? Assume that I have n0 = 2 and n = 4.Since n it's not <=0 int will enter on int f like `func(2,4-1);` then `func(2,3-1);` then `func(2,2-1);` and finally `func(2,1-1);`. Since n <= 0 it will return 0. Should't it stop there? Or `return f*f + n0;` will not do 0*0+2 and returning that value to `main` but f*f will do the recursive call again?

Comment: I'll tell you what your problem is: You are trying to **think** about recursion recursively (top to bottom)! That is really not the way to understand recursion, try to figure it out bottom to top. `f(n0, 0)` will be `0`. `f(n0, 1)` will be `f(n0, 0)^2 + n0 = 0^2 + n0` and so on...

Comment: More generally there are some mantras if you want to understand recursion: I told you the first: 1. "don't think about it recursively", 2. "assume you already have the answer for n-1 - and think about how to derive the answer for n", 3. answer the problem for small values directly (to assure that the recursion will end)

Comment: Thanks. My understanding It's a bit blurry but will try to figure it out.

Comment: When you want to understand how it works internally, you may want to look up how function calling actually works. Just search for "call stack" or similar. The important thing is, that the function arguments (and some different stuff) are pushed onto the stack, meaning that it grows; also local variables are typically also allocated on the stack, so you would in this example have multiple variables `f, n, n0`, each corresponding to one function call. Also each `return` will pop the last arguments and variables from the stack again, shrinking it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
int func(int n0, int n){
    if (n > 1){
        int nFinal = func(n0, --n);
        return (nFinal*nFinal) + n0;
    }
    return n0; // (0*0) + n0
}
```

note that `if (n == 1)` it returns `n0`, else it calls `func`, stores its return value in `nFinal` and returns `(nFinal*nFinal) + n0`.

Equivalent version of this function could call itself also for `n == 1` and `return 0` for `n == 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's on the same page as the one provided by Anthales. My doubts are the same as in is solution.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration, you do some math on the original value (and the parameter), then store it.  You have two broad choices about how to make it recursive.

1. Do all the iterations for `n-1` first, then do some more math on it before returning it.  This seems a more natural first go at making it recursive.
2. Do this iteration's math first, then pass the results in a recursive call to do the rest of the calculation.  This is tail recursive (which is unlikely to be of importance unless `n` is going to get really big and you know your compiler is going to optimise it away to save stack space ;-).

Recursion is like mathematical induction.  You need to think of your base case, and your induction step.  In your function, your base case is something like:

- If `n = 0`, then `func(n0, n)` returns `0`.

And your step is:

- `func(n0, n)` returns `func(n0,n-1) * func(n0,n-1) + n0`.  (You can call the function just once and save it to a local variable.)

This translates to a standard if-else construct.  See if you can understand it so far, if you get stuck let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func_r(int n0, int n, int acc);

int main (){
    int n0, n, nFinal;
    printf ("Enter constant (n0): ");
    scanf ("%d", &n0);
    printf ("Enter the number of iteractions (n): ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    nFinal = func_r(n0, n, 0);
    printf ("nFinal after %d iteractions is %d: \n", n, nFinal);
    return 0;
}

int func_r(int n0, int n, int acc){
    if(n == 0)
        return acc;
    return func_r(n0, n-1, acc*acc + n0);
}
```

Comment: Ideally I should maintain `int func(int n0, int n)` as it is. Nevertheless thanks for another solution